# Using a completely decoupled frontend with user authentication

Tags: html, backbone.js, angularjs, knockout.js, ember.js

I'm playing with the idea of having a completely decoupled HTML5 frontend, but still user authentication for a web app. Is this possible or will I run into some heavy browser security issues?

The idea is to have all static content delivered through a CDN on like example.com, and having it fetch dynamic data (and user authentication) through a separate subdomain, like api.example.com.
This would speed up the loading time of the site, and I could keep the frontend stuff in a completely separate repo so that the developers don't have to worry about setting up the backend to develop and test new features.

Is this already possible in some JS framework perhaps, backbone.js, angular.js, ember.js, knockout.js ?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is, but I think it is more about approach rather than technology. I have implemented what you describe for a project (it's online but don't want to do a shameless plug here, if interested to check it out I can post the link). My stack is java in the backend exposing a REST api for both autentication and business logic. The client is a backbone.js application. I explicitely decided NOT to use sessions at all. It is completely stateless. This of course means that the user must be re-authenticated at every request.

When the user logs in through a slightly modified OAuth endpoint, it gets a token that must be passed at every request. Cookie works in this case as they are handled automatically by the browser. If not passed as cookie, the backend expect it as a parameter. The frontend communicates using the REST endpoints. It's a single-page application, full client side, this means that the backend serves a page that is basically empty, that include few JS files that are the application itself. No other pageload occurs. Logout is done by simply deleting the cookie or not sending the authToken, the server cannot and doesn't have to "forget" about the user. Token are nice as they can be invalidated, both expilcitely or by changing the password. I've chosen this approach as it made it easy to develop desktop app and browser plugin for my webapp without touching a single line of backend code.